# How to test document.addEventListener('keydown', cb) with Mocha & Sinon?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, dom-events, sinon, keyboard-events

I'm trying to figure out the best way for testing this method:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    var modifiers = event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey ||
                    event.shiftKey;
    var mapped    = map[event.which];

    if (!modifiers) {
      if (mapped !== undefined) {
        event.preventDefault();
        self.emit("move", mapped);
      }
    }
  });
```

I'd like to ensure that if the keys are modifiers or if the keys are not mapped, nothing happens, however, if they are, to spy on the `self.emit` function.

Answer (score 1):

I could do it with sinon. Here is my solution:

```
it('adds listener events', function() {
  sinon.spy(document, 'addEventListener')
  sinon.spy(window, 'addEventListener')

  expect(document.addEventListener.calledOnce).not.to.be.true
  expect(window.addEventListener.calledOnce).not.to.be.true

  subject.myFunc()

  expect(document.addEventListener.calledOnce).to.be.true
  expect(window.addEventListener.calledOnce).to.be.true
})
```

In my case I had to test window `focus` and document `click` for example.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not testing what the OP is wanting to test. This is just testing whether `addEventListener` has been called. The OP want to test the behavior of the event handler added with `addEventListener`.

Comment: so, I did another separated test for my func that was called on listener. that was the easier way to make it happen

Comment: Yeah not correct answer, should test function in addEventListner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
before(function() {
  // Create stubs to spy on calls without executing the native code
  global.document= {addEventListener: sinon.stub()};
  global.self = {emit: sinon.stub()};

  // Execute the function under test
  subject.myFunc();

  // Save the callback function
  this.callback = document.addEventListener.getCalls()[0].args[1];
  this.eventType = document.addEventListener.getCalls()[0].args[0];
});

it('should use appropriate arguments', function() {
  this.eventType.should.eql("keydown");
  this.callback.should.be.a("function");
});

it('should use a callback that does nothing without a modifier key', function() {
  const eventProxy = {
    which: 97, // "A"
    preventDefault: sinon.stub()
  };

  this.callback(eventProxy);

  eventProxy.preventDefault.should.not.be.called;
  global.self.emit.should.not.be.called;
});

it('should use a callback that prevents default with a modifier key', function() {
  const eventProxy = {
    which: 97, // "A"
    shiftKey: true,
    preventDefault: sinon.stub()
  };

  this.callback(eventProxy);

  eventProxy.preventDefault.should.be.calledOnce.and.calledWith();
  global.self.emit.should.be.calledOnce.and.calledWith('move');
});
```